# Splitting Array into individuals strings

Tags: javascript

I want to split this array into individual strings. I tried the following code, but got stuck.

```
var myArray=[];
myArray=["Abdusalam Abubakar", "Mavissoulkin"];
function cutName("Salam"){
    var fullname=myArray[0];
    var splitting=fullname.split(" ");
    return splitting;
}
```

Comment: What is the desired outcome? Doesn't the array already contain individual strings? Note that you cannot use literals in the parameter definition.

Comment: And what's the reason for the `"Salam"` string in your function declaration (which makes it fail to parse, btw)?

Comment: I want to pass a string into the function as an argument. that's why the "salam" is there...

Comment: @Peace: What do you want to *do* with the argument? And why haven't you answered Felix's question?

Comment: @Peace: You may want to read the MDN JavaScript Guide, especially about functions: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Functions

Comment: am a beginner please, and this question is a test from my boss... please help. @T.J.Crowder and Felix Kling, Thanks for your support.

Comment: That's not an answer to Felix's question (or mine about the argument above), and I've *already* tried to help, to my best understanding of the question. We can't help you with a question we can't understand and which you show no sign of being willing to clarify.

Comment: ok. here is what am intendding to do: 
    First, declare an array named myArray
    Great! Now populate myArray with two strings.
    Put your full name in the first string, and your Skype handle in the second.
    Next, declare a function named cutName. It should take a string as an argument.
    cutName should return an array by breaking up the input string into individual words. For example "Douglas Crockford" should be returned as ["Douglas", "Crockford"]

Comment: did i answer your question sir?

Answer (score 1):

***If*** your goal is convert

```
["Abdusalam Abubakar", "Mavissoulkin"]
```

into

```
["Abdusalam", "Abubakar", "Mavissoulkin"]
```

you can do it by looping through the array, splitting the entries, and adding them to a new array, like so:

```js
var myArray = ["Abdusalam Abubakar", "Mavissoulkin"];
function cutName(a){
  var newArray = [];
  a.forEach(function(entry) {
    newArray.push.apply(newArray, entry.split(" "));
  });
  return newArray;
}
snippet.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(myArray));
snippet.log("After:  " + JSON.stringify(cutName(myArray)));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

The formation `newArray.push.apply(newArray, ...)` is a bit odd-looking: What it does is call `push` with a series of arguments given in the array you pass as the second argument, in effect calling `push` repeatedly.

Or if you like to make things really concise, you could use/abuse `Array#reduce`:

```js
var myArray = ["Abdusalam Abubakar", "Mavissoulkin"];
function cutName(a){
  return a.reduce(function(newArray, entry) {
    newArray.push.apply(newArray, entry.split(" "));
    return newArray;
  }, []);
}
snippet.log("Before: " + JSON.stringify(myArray));
snippet.log("After:  " + JSON.stringify(cutName(myArray)));
```

```html
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

`Array#reduce` calls the function you give it repeatedly, once for each entry in the array, passing in the "accumulator" you give it at the end as the first argument and the entry as the first. The value you return is used as the accumulator for the next call. It's possibly a bit OTT to use it for this, but...

Comment: I**M**HO you should've waited for OP to respond to your comment.

Comment: @AmitJoki: I really shouldn't be on SO at all right now... :-)

Comment: You can use `concat` or `splice` to join arrays, instead of writing your own loop.

Comment: @Barmar: We need the loop to loop through the values. I *could* have used `concat` within the loop, but it would create a new array every time. `splice` would be useful if I wanted to modify the original, sure.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder I don't think I got your comment(mind you I ain't a native English speaker). I hope that smiley at the end is what it is :)

Comment: @AmitJoki: :-) It means I should be doing something else and am being naughty spending time on SO at all, much less answering unclear questions. (And yup, the smiley is a smiley.)

Comment: @AmitJoki: And clearly you were right, as the OP has been back, posted a comment that clarified nothing, and not bothered to answer Felix's question, provid any kind of feedback on my answer, etc. ***sigh***

Comment: I was literally rofl *I want to pass a string into the function as an argument. that's why the "salam" is there...* The question is about to get closed anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
let myArray=["Abdusalam Abubakar", "Mavissoulkin"];
function cutName() {
  return myArray.toString().split('');
}
cutName();
```

Firstly convert the array into string using javascript *.toString();* you will get your string output.... than further use the *.split('');* to make individual character in to an array. If you want to join the string completely use *.join(' ');* to make a complete string out of the array...

```
output: [object Array]: ["A", "b", "d", "u", "s", "a", "l", "a", "m", " ", "A", "b", "u", "b", "a", "k", "a", "r", ",", "M"...]
0: "A"
1: "b"
2: "d"
3: "u"
4: "s"
5: "a"
6: "l"
7: "a"
8: "m"
9: " "
10: "A"
11: "b"
12: "u"
13: "b"
14: "a"
15: "k"
16: "a"
17: "r"
18: ","
19: "M"
20: "a"
21: "v"
22: "i"
23: "s"
24: "s"
25: "o"
26: "u"
27: "l"
28: "k"
29: "i"
30: "n"
length: "31"
```